# Get more information about compiler errors in Clion

Tags: c++, clion

I have a program with many files and right now I have a huge bunch of compiler errors which I have a hard time understanding. The only line references I get are references to C++ libraries, such as algorithm or utility.

My question is: how am I supposed to know where the compiler error is? Some line in my code obviously generated an error in a C++ library, but where was it generated? Is there any way to get more info about the compiler errors? It's not like I can debug it, since it's in compile time.

EDIT: I realize this could be difficult to understand. Here are some examples of errors which I have modified for simplicity reasons.

(1) Here the error is on a line which includes std::string and I have no idea where it tries to do something with ClassY.

```
In file included from [my path]/ClassX.cpp:1:
In file included from [my path]/ClassX.h:4:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/string:439:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:2123:24:
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('my project::ClassY *' and 'const my project::ClassY')
```

EDIT 2: problem solved. There were in total 31 error lines and note lines. I thought these had nothing to do with the above. However, they were all connected to one single line, which was referenced further down in the error messages:

```
myvec.erase(std::remove(myvec.begin(), myvec.end(), item), myvec.end());
```

Comment: What compiler are you using, and on what platform? Please post the actual error message. In my experience CLion prints the full error, which should include exactly where in your code the error is (just maybe not as the first line).

Comment: When you get errors in the standard library headers it's usually because of problems with templates. The error log should then contains something like "instantiated from..." or similar, which tells you where in your code the error is.

Comment: My mind-reading ability is apparently poor today, so I can't even capture whether you are getting an error during linking or during compilation. It would PROBABLY help if you posted the actual error(s) - at leas the first few, and preferrably some information about what the code is that you are compiling to cause the problem.

Comment: So you are passing a pointer where the function (or operator) expects a value. Instead of `mythingPtr`, use `*mythingPtr`.

Comment: [I edited your error message and inserted a couple of newlines to make it a bit more readable]

Comment: Okay, sure, but where do I do that? Since the error message only points to an #include statement and the error is within the algorithm library, I don't know where in the code I have messed up.

Comment: I would have hoped that there was another line after that saying "called from ..."? Otherwise, find what function it is, and find where you are using it.

Comment: That can't be a proper error message, `const my project`? `my project` doesn't sound like a valid namespace or class.

Comment: That's not the real name. The blank space should not be there, however :)

Comment: The "note" lines are part of the complete error message, and often contains very exact hints about what the problem is, where it is, and sometimes even how to fix it.